# Growth of $()$ satisfying $t(n)=2^nt(n/2)+n^n$

Tags: asymptotics

$t(n)=2^nt(n/2)+n^n$

I can't use Master Theorem becaus $2^n$ and althought I am familiar with other Recursive Tree method, I can't solve it. Is there a chance solve it using Recursive Tree method?

Answer (score 0):

One approach
$$
\begin{split}
t_n
 &= 2^n t_{n/2} + n^n \\
 &= 2^n \left[2^{n/2} t_{n/4} + (n/2)^{n/2}\right] + n^n \\
 &= 2^{n + n/2} t_{n/4} + 2^n (n/2)^{n/2} + n^n \\
 &= 2^{2n - n/2} t_{n/4} + 2^{n/2} n^{n/2} + n^n \\
 &= 2^{2n - n/2} \left[2^{n/4} t_{n/8} + (n/4)^{n/4}\right] + 2^{n/2} n^{n/2} + n^n \\
 &= 2^{2n - n/4} t_{n/8} + 2^{2n - n/2} \left[(n/4)^{n/4}\right] + 2^{n/2} n^{n/2} + n^n \\
 &= 2^{2n - n/4} t_{n/8} + 2^n n^{n/4} + 2^{n/2} n^{n/2} + n^n \\
\end{split}
$$
and you can iterate a couple more terms until yousee the pattern...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a non-homogeneous difference equation.

\begin{equation}
t(n)-2^{n} t(n / 2)=n^{n}
\end{equation}